# Configure Apache2 to work on a new MacBook Pro 10.14

Tags: php, macos, apache, apache2, macos-mojave

[image]

So I just bought a brand **new** *MacBook Pro 2019*, restore it from Time Machine.
Most of my files are restored, but Apache2 configurations seem not fully restored.
My local site that used to work, but now **not** working. All my Apache2 settings seem to reset back to default.

## I've tried :

Open up : `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Uncomment this line

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and

```
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

and

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

and

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

This is one of my vhost record from `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >
    ServerName boss.test
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/bheng/Sites/laravel/boss-portal/public"
    UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>
```

and I restart my Apache as I go `sudo apachectl -k restart`

I have this line : `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   boss.test
```

When I goto `boss.test`

## I kept seeing :

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

[image]

Just to try it out, I even try

```
sudo chmod -R 777 vendor/ storage/ public/
```

Still same result

What steps am I missing ?

Comment: Did you add `index.php` to the `DirectoryIndex` in your apache config? Also, if you add an `index.html`, is it working?

Comment: It is a laravel site. Yes, `index.php` is in `/Users/bheng/Sites/laravel/boss-portal/public`.

Comment: What I mean is did you add `DirectoryIndex index.php` in your `httpd.conf`? Not if you had an `index.php` in the `public` folder.

Comment: It seems there already in line 283. See this img : https://i.imgur.com/9puzwZk.png

Comment: You need to add `index.php`. Right now it's only looking for `index.html`. So it should be: `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php`

Comment: ok. I did that save the file, and restart `sudo apachectl -k restart` - same ‍♂️

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194493/discussion-between-chin-leung-and-kyo).